# How to make a VM on a bridged network interface accessible from LAN?

Tags: virtual-machine, routing, bridge, qemu, libvirt

### Context

I have the following network :

- a `router` (IP `192.168.2.254`) which handles DHCP on 192.168.2.x network
- a `computer1` (IP `192.168.2.1`) under Linux (Debian 11) using ufw as firewall
- a `computer2` (IP `192.168.2.2`) under Linux (Debian 11)
- other computers on the LAN `computerN` (IP `192.168.2.N`) under various OSes

Basically, what I want to achieve is to have a virtual machine `vm` hosted on `computer1` and allow network traffic :

- from `vm` to `computer1`
- from `computer1` to `vm`
- from `vm` to `computerN`
- from `computerN` to `vm`

In other words, I want my `vm` to work on the network as if it was one of `computerN` systems.

I used VirtualBox for a long time and it works flawlessly with the VM's network interface in bridged mode, with the extra benefit that VM's IP is handled by LAN DHCP (192.168.2.x). But I have to try an other virtualization solution since I experience compatibility problems with latest kernels.

I give a try to Qemu/KVM with libvirt (using libvirt-manager as GUI).

### What I've done

On `computer1` :

- I enabled the bridge network `virbr0` given by libvirt, which has a DHCP with 192.168.122.x range
- I created and set up a Linux (Debian 11) system on a virtual machine `vm` with `virbr0` associated to the network interface
- `vm` gets the IP address `192.168.122.184`
- `vm` can ping `computer1` (its host) and `computerN` (other computer on the LAN)
- `computer1` can ping `vm`
- **`computerN` can not ping `vm`**

### What I've tried

- enabling IPv4 forwarding on `computer1`, so `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`
- allowing forwarding on `computer1`'s firewall with `sudo ufw route allow in on enp41s0 out on virbr0`
- defining a static route on `router` and/or `computerN` (`ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 via 192.168.2.1`)

Without the route added, a ping from `192.168.2.2` to `192.168.122.184` just timeouts.

#### With the route defined directly on `192.168.2.2`

Ping gives :

```
PING 192.168.122.184 (192.168.122.184) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
```

and traceroute shows :

```
traceroute to 192.168.122.184 (192.168.122.184), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.981 ms  0.920 ms  0.869 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.824 ms  0.780 ms  0.477 ms
```

and `tcpdump -ni any icmp` on `computer1` shows :

```
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
04:27:31.443991 enp41s0 In  IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.122.184: ICMP echo request, id 19733, seq 1, length 64
04:27:31.444022 enp41s0 Out IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP 192.168.122.184 protocol 1 port 32450 unreachable, length 92
04:27:32.456447 enp41s0 In  IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.122.184: ICMP echo request, id 19733, seq 2, length 64
04:27:32.456477 enp41s0 Out IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP 192.168.122.184 protocol 1 port 52880 unreachable, length 92
04:27:33.480449 enp41s0 In  IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.122.184: ICMP echo request, id 19733, seq 3, length 64
04:27:33.480481 enp41s0 Out IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP 192.168.122.184 protocol 1 port 3122 unreachable, length 92
04:27:34.504454 enp41s0 In  IP 192.168.2.2 > 192.168.122.184: ICMP echo request, id 19733, seq 4, length 64
04:27:34.504484 enp41s0 Out IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.2: ICMP 192.168.122.184 protocol 1 port 16339 unreachable, length 92
```

#### With the route defined on `router`

Ping gives :

```
PING 192.168.122.184 (192.168.122.184) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.1)
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.1)
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.1)
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=5 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.1)
From 192.168.2.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Port Unreachable
```

and traceroute shows :

```
traceroute to 192.168.122.184 (192.168.122.184), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.254 (192.168.2.254)  0.336 ms  0.478 ms  0.657 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.958 ms  1.084 ms  1.234 ms
 3  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  1.188 ms  1.320 ms  1.284 ms
```

#### Disabling firewall

I tried to disable ufw firewall (`ufw disable`) on `computer1` with the same results.

##### `iptables-save` output on `computer1` before disabling firewall :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:22 2022
```

##### `nft list ruleset` output on `computer1` before disabling firewall :

```
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 65 bytes 7530 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 108 bytes 6480 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 3 bytes 194 return
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 909 bytes 700373 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 747 bytes 64760 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }
}
table ip mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 # CHECKSUM fill
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 787 bytes 72954 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 15 bytes 1937 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 27 bytes 2765 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 40 bytes 4562 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
```

##### `iptables-save` output on `computer1` after disabling firewall :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [30:1796]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34:1684]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:20:57 2022
```

##### `nft list ruleset` output on `computer1` after disabling firewall :

```
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 69 bytes 7825 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 125 bytes 7500 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 4 bytes 267 return
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 937 bytes 702052 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 775 bytes 66099 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }
}
table ip mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 # CHECKSUM fill
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 817 bytes 74439 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 16 bytes 2030 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 28 bytes 2858 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 42 bytes 4748 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
```

##### `iptables-save` output on `computer1` after disabling firewall and reboot :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jul 16 11:28:44 2022
```

##### `nft list ruleset` output on `computer1` after disabling firewall and reboot :

```
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 3 bytes 246 return
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 1 bytes 60 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 2 bytes 142 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
        counter packets 30 bytes 6587 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 60 bytes 3600 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain DOCKER {
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 1949 bytes 103516 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 67 counter packets 2 bytes 660 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 189 bytes 24036 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 2 bytes 660 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 211 bytes 24948 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 1949 bytes 103516 accept
        iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state related,established counter packets 4503 bytes 6147360 accept
        oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 6452 bytes 6250876 return
    }
}
table ip mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 2 bytes 660 # CHECKSUM fill
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 6724 bytes 6289565 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 32 bytes 4339 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 55 bytes 5939 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 85 bytes 10138 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a(n "internal") bridge is not the same thing as "bridged" networking (which refers to the fact that a physical NIC being enslaved to the bridge used by the VMs, i.e. merging the physical and virtual LAN into one broadcast domain). You should decide / declare whether you want "bridged" networking back or switch to the "internal" bridge (i.e. routed) approach first.

Comment: If I understand your question right, what I have here is an "internal" bridge.

Comment: Yes, if you are fine with that, you can try something like `tcpdump -ni any icmp` on `computer 1`. To make sure firewall really isn't the issue, check `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset`. Btw is there anything quirky in your setup? All the LAN hosts still use `.254` as their default gateway right?

Comment: For sure, I added tcpdump result in my question. And yes, all hosts use .254 as default gateway.

Comment: Again, I'd suggest that you check `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` after disabling ufw. (If possible, also reboot as well to eliminate the noise / leftover.)

Comment: I added outputs of both commands in my question : before, after disabling ufw, and after reboot.

Comment: As I've guessed, there's something else messing with your firewall, in this case libvirt. I'm not sure what's the way to prevent that, maybe creating another "internal" bridge and use that instead will do.

Comment: FWIW, the rules in `LIBVIRT_FWI` is why you can't ping from the outside: only replies are allow back in.

Comment: Also the mere fact of running Docker will get bridged packets handled by iptables (and/or nftables in ip families). So even if the bridge was on the LAN there would be problems. Network experiment should always be done first with Docker disabled completely and the system rebooted.